# Remove rows based on aggregate count

Tags: python, pandas

Having a dataframe like this

```
car model
toyota corolla
toyota rav4
honda  civic
honda  civic
honda  accord
```

How can I write a remove brands that occur less than n number of times, say I want to remove brands that occur less than 3 times the resulting dataframe will be

```
car model
honda  civic
honda  civic
honda  accord
```

So I keep the same dataframe and all variables and just remove the rows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use, `groupby` with `filter` like this:

```
 df.groupby('car').filter(lambda x: x['car'].count() >= 3)
```

Output:

```
     car   model
2  honda   civic
3  honda   civic
4  honda  accord
```

Or use boolean indexing, with `groupby` and `transform`:

```
df[df.groupby('car')['car'].transform('count') >= 3]
```

Answer (score 5):

```py
In [22]: df.assign(cnt=df.groupby('car').transform(len)).query('cnt >= 3').drop('cnt', axis=1)
Out[22]:
     car   model
2  honda   civic
3  honda   civic
4  honda  accord
```

1. you get the counts per car using `df.groupby('car').transform(len)`
2. assign the counts to a column using `df.assign`
3. filter where count >= 3
4. drop the count column